# applying ng-click to options in a select box using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I havent used angular before but I am trying to get this working. the code worked for me as a list, but I would like to get the same thing working using a select drop down. Can someone help please?

`<select ng-model="data.selectedOption">
   <option ng-click="myFilter = {pay_status : 'Paid'}" value="Paid Work">Paid Work</option>
   <option ng-click="myFilter = {pay_status : 'Volunteer'}" value="Volunteer Work">Volunteer Work</option>
   <option ng-click="myFilter = {opento : 'Undergraduates'}" value="Undergraduates">Undergraduates</option>
   <option ng-click="myFilter = {opento : 'Postgraduates'}" value="Postgraduates">Postgraduates</option>
</select> </div>`

I used to have the same code (the ng-click etc) using a list and it worked so I was hoping that I could do the same thing for option but no... what is it that I need to change?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your select directive to bind to your data through a controller

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <select
    ng-model="myFilter"
    ng-options="value.label for value in myFilters">
        <option>--</option>
  </select>
  <div>
    myFilter: {{myFilter.filter}}
  </div>
</div>
```

and your JS like

```
function myCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.myFilters = [{
        "filter": {pay_status : 'Paid'},
        "label": "Paid Work"
    },{
        "filter": {pay_status : 'Volunteer'},
        "label": "Volunteer Work"
    },{
        "filter": {opento : 'Undergraduates'},
        "label": "Undergraduates"
    },{
        "filter": {opento : 'Postgraduates'},
        "label": "Postgraduates"
    }];

};
```

See the fiddle: - http://jsfiddle.net/vxvcbrxs/